# Angular JS - How to reset / reload an angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone knows how to exactly reset / reload an angular app?

```
var dtApp = angular.module('App1', []);
dtApp.controller('Cont1', function($scope)
{
    $scope.sel1 = {
    '1':{title:'1X', val:'1'},
    '2':{title:'2X', val:'2'},
    '3':{title:'3X', val:'3'},
    '5':{title:'5X', val:'5'},
    }; 

    $scope.xyz='123';
    $scope.func_1();
});
.
.
.

<input type='text' ng-model='xyz' />
<select ng-options='v.title for v in sel1'></select>
<input type='text' value='{{sel1.val}}' />
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check this : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. We can do it using the following steps as an example

1) Put the default values in a separate function:

```
function controller_defaults($scope)
{
    $scope.xyz='123';
    $scope.func_1();
}
```

2) setup a reset function in the controller:

```
dtApp.controller('Cont1', function($scope)
{
    $scope.resetx = function()
    {
        controller_defaults($scope);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

3) call the reset function from outside the angular code, e.g. a button click:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("cont_tag_id")).scope().resetx();
document.getElementById('form_id').reset(); //additional work to reset rest of the form
```